# How to get HTML leaderboard into discord channel that auto updates

Tags: html, parsing, discord, embed, leaderboard

Is there anyway I can make this leaderboard show in a discord channel as as embedded or parae it to look directly like that, but show in a channel a dn auto update?

I’ve been trying all day and all I can do it get texts files to show on discord or a slipper sloppy website parse. Please Somone else , I just want to top 5-10 leaderboards user and for it to auto-update maybe every hour

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LfGiC.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [Webhooks](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks)?

[This Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/HytaleInfo/comments/ayz7q4/how_to_make_a_discord_webhook_that_automatically/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share) explains the process in detail

A [Discord Bot](https://discordjs.guide/#before-you-begin) might also be usable in this case